# VB.Net how to read a compressed text file directly into an array of strings

Tags: vb.net, file-io, zip

Is it possible to read a zipped text file like a normal text file without having to extract it first, and if so, how? Currently, I have to extract the file, read all the lines to an array of strings, and then delete the extracted file.

```
Dim arrLines() As String
Try
    oApp.Namespace(Application.StartupPath).CopyHere(oApp.Namespace(strZipFilename).Items.Item(CStr(filename)))
    arrLines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\" & filename)
    Dim FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FSO.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\" & filename)
Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
End Try
'do stuff with arrLines...
```

I would prefer not to need to do this. If someone could tell me how to do something like `IO.File.ReadAllLines(oApp.Namespace(strZipFilename).Items.Item(CStr(filename)))` WITHOUT using third-party libraries, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: +1 to undo mean anonymous downvote. I don't know how to answer this in vb.net, but it's a perfectly reasonable question. BTW, this is definitely possible, you *can* uncompress a zip file in memory, though I don't know if vb.net has standard libraries to do that.

Comment: Thanks. Confirmation that it is possible means an answer might be out there somewhere, though I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by:

1. Add references of System.IO.Comression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
2. Add Imports of System.IO.Compression

You can then use the following code to read the content to a file and store it to a string variable.  In this particular example, I have the compressed file name "File1.txt" stored in a textbox on the main form (tbFile) and I have the contents of the compressed file displayed in a textbox (tb1) on the main form.

```
Private Sub bRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bRead.Click
    Try
        Using archive As ZipArchive = Compression.ZipFile.Open(zipDest, ZipArchiveMode.Read)
            Dim entry As ZipArchiveEntry = archive.GetEntry(tbFile.Text)
            Dim s As String = ""
            Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(entry.Open())
                s = sr.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
            tb1.Text = s
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't test right now, but this looks like exactly what I was looking for at the time

Comment: No problem. Technology changes and better answers to old questions come about. I have no idea if this was possible back then, but for anyone with the same problem now, it's good that this answer was posted.

Comment: Looking over the documentation for these packages, this is exactly what I had in mind when I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for reading a GZip compressed stream and returning the text of the compressed file one line at a time.  Without third party libraries, it's not currently possible to unzip a file compressed with PKZip.  System.IO.Packaging will unzip some files, but it's relatively limited.  There is some [hope](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/28/working-with-zip-files-in-net.aspx) for a [feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/07/29/more-on-zip-in-net-richard-lee.aspx) built in, however.

```
    Public Shared Iterator Function ReadAllCompressedLines(path As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Using rawStream = New System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read)
            Using cstream = New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(rawStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
                Dim currLine As String = ""
                Dim currentByte As Integer
                currentByte = cstream.ReadByte()
                While currentByte <> -1
                    currLine += Convert.ToChar(currentByte)
                    If currLine.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then
                        Dim rc = Trim(currLine)
                        If rc.Length > 0 Then
                            Yield rc
                        End If
                        currLine = ""
                    End If
                    currentByte = cstream.ReadByte()
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Shared Function Trim(currLine As String) As String
        '\x00EF\x00BB\x00BF
        Return currLine.TrimEnd(ControlChars.Cr, ControlChars.Lf).TrimStart(Convert.ToChar(&HEF), Convert.ToChar(&HBB), Convert.ToChar(&HBF))
    End Function
```

Comment: This is great. I was trying so hard to do it all in one step that I overlooked reading a line at a time.